# find ul if it's parent elements is li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html is this

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So i want to add all classes to the elements via Jquery.I want to add data-toggle attribute via Jquery.I'm doing it like bellow but it's not 100% correct.I want to find `ul` if it i's parent element is `li` and add class to the `ul` and to the parent element

JQUERY

```
$(".nav-collapse").find("ul").first().addClass("nav");
 $(".nav-collapse").find("li").hast("ul").addClass("nav");
$(".nav").find("li a").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown").append("<b class='caret'></b>");
$(".nav").find("li ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");
$(".nav").find("li ul li").addClass("dropdown-submenu");
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all ul's then filter only those items whose parent is a `li`

```
$('ul').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().is('li')
}).addClass('dropdown-menu')
```

for second case in comment

> add dropdown class to the li if it has ul elements as child

```
$('li:has(ul)').addClass('dropdown')
```

Comment: we can't select it using ul.dropdown-menu because those elements comes without any Class.

Comment: @loading...  so just remove class in selector

Comment: i want to add dropdown class to the li if it has ul elements as child's .and i i want to add dropdown-menu class to the ul if it has li elemnts as parents

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find ul if it i's parent element is li

```
$("li > ul")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if($('li>ul:first')){
        $('li>ul:first').addClass('dropDown-menu');
        $('.dropDown-menu').parent().addClass('dropDown');
    }
```

I have made use of :first, just as a precaution to avoid applying the class if another UL exists within the li tags.